# How to start looping a function after button was pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android application that serves as house guard. For now it works like this: after pressing a button it takes picture without intent, compare it with the picture taken last time, if there's a significant difference it saves it, sends sms and uploads picture using ftp. I'm new to Java and Android...

```
@Nullable
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        [...]
        //Take a picture
        view.findViewById(R.id.capture_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Take picture using the camera without preview.
                //...wanted to put here for loop but didn't work
                takePicture();
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------

   protected void takePicture() {
        if (mCameraPreview != null) {
            if (mCameraPreview.isSafeToTakePictureInternal()) {
                mCameraPreview.takePictureInternal();
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Background camera not initialized. Call startCamera() to initialize the camera.");
        }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------

@Override
    public void onImageCapture(@NonNull File imageFile) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

    // here it compares last and old picture 
    [...]

        // if comparison failed alert
        new FtpTask().execute(path);
    sendSMS("767555444", "ALARM ALARM");
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------

void takePictureInternal() {
        safeToTakePicture = false;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Convert byte array to bitmap
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            //Rotate the bitmap
                            Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
                            if (mCameraConfig.getImageRotation() != CameraRotation.ROTATION_0) {
                                rotatedBitmap = HiddenCameraUtils.rotateBitmap(bitmap, mCameraConfig.getImageRotation());

                                //noinspection UnusedAssignment
                                bitmap = null;
                            } else {
                                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                            }

                            //Save image to the file.
                            if (HiddenCameraUtils.saveImageFromFile(rotatedBitmap,
                                    mCameraConfig.getImageFile(),
                                    mCameraConfig.getImageFormat())) {
                                //Post image file to the main thread
                                new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mCameraCallbacks.onImageCapture(mCameraConfig.getImageFile());
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                //Post error to the main thread
                                new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mCameraCallbacks.onCameraError(CameraError.ERROR_IMAGE_WRITE_FAILED);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            mCamera.startPreview();
                            safeToTakePicture = true;
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mCameraCallbacks.onCameraError(CameraError.ERROR_CAMERA_OPEN_FAILED);
            safeToTakePicture = true;
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is that after button press it starts the loop in which pictures are taken and compared again and again until I stop by clicking the button. I don't want new loop to start before old one is still being processed (image comparison pixel by pixel takes time). Being more precise, I want to ask where exactly should I add a loop to make it works?

Sorry if there is too much or too little code. If I forgot to add something please tell me and I'll upload.

Comment: definitely multithreaded if you want to keep the ui thread alive and probably call `sleep(<a bit>);`  every round

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you will be better off with the camera capture session.

See this article - it should help you understand what you can do: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-android-camera-capture-sessions-and-requests-4e54d9150295